# Login Filter вопрос

Tags: java, servlet, filter

Написал Логин Фильтр, который не будем пропускать не авторизованного юзера :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае при авторизации он перекидывает меня обратно на страницу логина, то есть условие if не срабатывает.
Но если добавить проверку по URI :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То все работает хорошо!
Я не могу понять почему так? Зачем эта проверка. Пожалуйста обьясните как это работает.

Comment: даже если в данном случае это не так принципиально, в дальнейшем откажитесь пожалуйста от скринов кода, и выкладывайте его копипастом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что редирект на страницу логина тоже проходит через это фильтр

Comment: Элементарно, но почему-то никак не могло у меня это в голове проясниться